# How to create new instance based on array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For every level, there is an array of coordinates that I want to create new instances based on. I am wondering how to go about doing this. Here's what I have so far.

```
    function levelDots(level){
        var renderLevel = {
                    1: [(100, 100), (200, 200)], //not sure if this is correct,  e.g (100, 100) would correspond to (x,y)
                    2: [(50,50), (75,75)]
                }


        renderLevel[level].each(function(){ //not sure what to put inbetween function()
            dots.push(new dot(x,y))
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(x, y)` returns `y` in javascript, use an array `[100, 100]` or object `{x: 100, y: 100}` to represent the value.

***Example:***

```
function levelDots(level) {
    var renderLevel = {
        level1: [
            [100, 100],
            [200, 200]
        ],
        level2: [
            [50, 50],
            [75, 75]
        ]
    };
    return renderLevel[level].map(function (el) {
        return new dot(el[0], el[1]);
    });
}
```